# Generate Separate Font Files

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-size

Is it possible to generate separate font files from a original file. Meaning I have different font styles for bold & italic? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"Possible"? Yes, but it's not quite so straightforward as that.

Font manipulation tools exist that can read an original file and perform font-wide manipulations such as emboldening & slanting ("italic"), and you can then generate the derived font styles. So, it is technically correct to say that it is "possible". And in fact, many operating systems employ something like this on-the-fly (at rendering time) to produce "fake" bold and italic fonts where there is no real instance. However:

1) Simple mathematical emboldening and slanting of base ("Regular") designs often introduces undesirable artifacts that require clean-up. Performing that clean-up assumes some level of familiarity with font design principles and tooling, as well as the original font design itself. People involved in this area of work spend *years* studying and practicing how to do this well.

2) Many fonts that you use every day are provided to you under license, and in some cases that license does not allow you to distribute derivative works of the original. So if you decide to go this route, be certain that the base font's license allows manipulation and distribution of said derivatives (unless you only care about it for personal use).